# Change Order Status to custom status after order is complete

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status

I need a way to change the Order Status after the order has been marked as complete.

I would also like a custom status so that my colleague understands the reason it has been changed

I want this to be done in Admin back end and not in the Database.

I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage order status in backend of magento under system > order statuses

Comment: I don't want to change the name of the status or use an already existing status. My main goal is to change the status of an order after it has been marked as complete

Comment: you can add a new **state** that is assigned to the **status** "complete". States within the same status can be changed for each order in the backend (above the comment history). The main **statuses** have internal meanings and should normally not be changed.

Comment: I like that I can change the status name of certain orders but I have a module that collects the data if its processed but I want to exclude certain orders.